# Xcode Could not launch “App Name” The app's bundle identifier “...” is being used by another running app

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ipad

Trying to run a Mac (Designed for iPad) app on my mac and it is refusing to run due to the below error:

> The app's bundle identifier “...” is being used by another running
> app. macOS does not support running iOS or Mac Catalyst apps
> concurrently with other apps using the same bundle identifier. Please
> try again after terminating all other processes using the same bundle
> identifier or changing the bundle identifier of your app.

I don't have any apps running with the same bundle id. I tried deleting derived data, doing a clean, restarting Xcode. Same error. It was previously working without any issues.

Answer (score 2):

Open the Activity Monitor –> search for the name of the scheme you ran previously –> double click and force quit it. Should work after that.